# Fill data from one form to another form grid view

Tags: c#

I have a form1 and form2. in form1 there is a textbox which consist any department. and the another textbox consist room related to only these depatment. besides room textbox there is a searchbutton. which opens form2. form 2 consist a gridview. and this grid view should be filled by only selected department in form1. and when this form2 opens then in grid view also shows room is booked or free...

Its for the Wndows Application.

Comment: @viwek , is it win forms?? if so are you comfirdable with events and delegates.

Comment: Is this a web application, or a Windows application?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you can pass any information to Form2 via its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a constructor for Form2 which take arguments; the parameters you want to pass to next Form2.

Like

```
public class Form2: Form
{
private string _department;
public Form2(string department)
{
InitializeComponents();
_department = department;
}
}
```

And you can consume it like this

```
button1_Click()
{
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(txtDepartment.Text);
frm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Also you can do this via properties.

```
public class Form2: Form
{
public string Department
{
get;set;
}
}
```

like this

```
button1_Click()
{
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Department = txtDepartment.Text
frm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Then how the grid view will filled related to only txtDepartment??

Comment: You have to write the logic, if you are binding a DataTable; you can do a DataTable.Select method.

Comment: You need to provide which datasource you are binding.

Comment: What datasource binding to gridview. You need to search for department in the DataSource.

Comment: Anuraj i m asking u how i do that for my HOSPITAL_POINT data

Comment: What logic you need are planning to fill the GridView?

Comment: I want when i select any department in form1 text box then the grid view of form2 filled by only related to this department rows.

Comment: Okay, Is Department details stored in the Database?

Comment: You can pass the Textbox value to SQL and based on the Query you can do this. Also you can do a filter on DataTable using DataTable.Select() or DataTable.Find() method.

Comment: m not understanding what u r saying.